# Are there outdated prescriptive norms in Russian?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Jim Kovpak wrote an article *A Quick and Dirty Guide to Russian* that frequently references 'Russian being an extremely hard language and even natives make mistakes speaking it', but never really builds up on that or gives any examples.

I've also heard that many Russian youth and some adults say *"Христос воскрес!"* instead of *Христос воскресе!* for Easter, but I don't feel like that counts because this is more so Church Slavonic influences of Russian and not mistakes in Russian proper.

I'm mostly interested in words which are not used anymore the way the dictionaries and style guides prescribe them to be used, like how in American English the pronunciation of Stephen as *Steffen* is now a commonality, even if proscribed; or saying 'vice-a-versa'.

Comment: I noticed this question is on hold for being too broad, but I haven't a clue on how to change it. Looks like I'll have to delete it probably? Admin help?

Comment: First of all, we discourage open list questions: for a question to be good for this site, it should have an "ideal" answer none should be able to add to, and this "ideal" answer should be short enough to fit into one post.

Comment: Besides, what exactly is "mistake that became a part of the language"? To a person from early XX century that would be using _пирожное_ as a countable noun; to one from early XIX that would be using _наверное_ in the sense of "maybe"; to the author of The Tale of Igor's Campaign, the whole modern Russian would sound as one big mistake. The problem is, once it's a part of the language, it's not a mistake anymore.

Comment: Oh okay, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: thanks to @Quassnoi for those excellent explanations, to the author - honestly, I can hardly can think of how this particular question can be edited to become on-topic.

Comment: @Judicaël: I think you need to ask this the other way around: "are there some outdated prescriptive norms in Russian"? There are indeed some words (_толика, гренок_ etc.) which no Russian in their sane mind uses the way the dictionary prescribes them to be used, and there are few enough of them to fit into one answer.

Comment: http://luchshe-molchi.livejournal.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Христос воскрес** really is a borderline case since it's correct Russian.

As for actual "mistakes" — let's first establish what we consider a mistake. I'm going to disregard popular prescriptivist tics such as the crusade against *одеть пальто* (insisting on **надеть пальто**), and other examples that are considered jarring and "uncultured" on the questionable premise that everyday language is a thing that can and should be regulated. Let's limit ourselves with those cases where the speaker is clearly aiming for the formal/literary register while breaking some of its expected norms.

A lot of such mistakes have to do with misplaced stress, such as *дóговор* instead of **договóр**, and with oblique cases of large numerals: by far not all native speakers will get through **тысячей семьюстами шестьюдесятью** without stumbling or using the wrong ending somewhere.

Others are more specific:

- *Не* instead of **ни** in "whatever/whoever/wherever" constructions. Since they sound the same except in one case, with the past tense of **быть**, this mostly only results in spelling mistakes, but you do also get *что бы это нé было* instead of **что бы это ни было**.
- Lack of agreement of verbal adverb phrases with the subject of the main clause. Often exemplified with **Проезжая мимо станции, с меня слетела шляпа** (a shortened and slightly paraphrased quote from a story by Chekhov, where it's used deliberately for comedic effect.)
- A duplicate *бы* somewhere down the line in a long subordinate clause that already began with **чтобы**.
- *Обоих*/*обоим* where **обеих**/**обеим** is expected.
- Similar to the previous item: using the forms **двое**, **трое**, etc. with female-only groups. (Not currently a prominent part of our gendered language debates that I'm aware of, but one can certainly expect calls for retiring this distinction at some point. For now, it's bad grammar.)
- Genitive instead of dative with **согласно** "according to".

Just the ones I could think of off the top of my head; I don't also want to veer into what's no longer issues of pure grammar rather than style, such as people mixing up **неприкасаемый** and **неприкосновенный**, or arguing whether **другая альтернатива** is or isn't a tautology.

Comment: координально вместе кардинально, обои вместо обе, "в этой связи" и много много прочих. 
в общем, человека просто надо отправлять на форумы типа "лучше молчи", где такие ошибки собирают и над ними плачут/смеются

Comment: Another example is wrong use of a comparative degree of adjectives: "мы стали более лучше одеваться".

Comment: @arioch: when someone says *координально* and the dictionary has it as *кардинально*, it's the person who has it wrong. When someone says *гренка* and the dictionary has it as *гренок*, it's the dictionary that has it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Some examples:
 1. "Ложить" instead if "класть";
 2. Wrong accentuation, e.g. "зво́нит/звони́т";
 3. "Одеть" instead of "надеть";
 4. "Хорошее кофе" instead of "хороший кофе" (indeed both forms are legal now);
 5. "Ихний", "ейный" and similar nonexistent words;
 6. "Сколько время" instead of "сколько времени".

Comment: also, I've heard that first it was correct to say "библиОтека", but saying "библиотЕка" was such a usual mistake that overtime it became standard pronunciation. And you forgot "-тся/-ться". Plus some natives can write something "ты будишь макароны?" indicating that "-ишь/-ешь" is also quite a common mistake

Comment: IMHO question was about spoken language, so I made exampes of mistakes in speech. BTW, questions has been cheanged, so my answer is irrelevant now.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm mostly interested in **words** which are not used in the real language
>   the way the dictionaries and style guides prescribe them to be used.

Oh, there are a lot of them, especially in journalism and in emerging areas which have a lot of loan words, e.g.:

- *нелицеприятный* is used as *unpleasant* but means *objective*
- *усугубить* is used as *worsen* but means *intensify* with no negative meaning
- *линейка* is used as *(model) line* but means a *ruler*
- *эскпертиза* is used as *knowledge* due to blending with its English counterpart
- *бизнесы* is more often used in plural

Comment: So which of these dictionary meanings are outdated?

Comment: None are outdated. But in 'real language' their 'real' dictionary meaning (which are on the right in my examples) is rarely used because of lack of proper education.

Comment: I've clarified the question body a little bit. Basically we're looking for the terms which are not used anymore the way dictionaries tell us to use them. Are you saying *линейка* does not mean "ruler" in spoken Russian nowadays?

Comment: It is still used, of course. This is an important clarification. In this case with *линейка*, the word is used with a meaning not fixed in any dictionary. However, for нелицеприятный and усугубить my answer still holds, IMO; few people use them right.

Comment: I cannot agree about "нелицеприятный" and "усугубить". Meaning of these words  has been changed. Dictionaries will be changed some time later.

Comment: @edo1 Has been changed by whom? Even in the modern Kuznetzov's dictionary they are not changed, thus not considered a cultural norm. Actually, they are offsprings of bureaucratic, "more serious" language used incorrectly.